# Configurable swatches is not functionally working in Magento 1.9. Still asking "Please select items"

Tags: swatches

In my theme (bought from themeforest) Configurable swatches is integrated technically but not working functionaly. I can see the swatches in my Product page but when I click on them upon add to cart its showing error "Please select item". When I disable the Configurable swatches then traditional drop-down field is come up and its working.

So I wanted to know why configurable watches is not working? Googled a lot but no answer. Please guys help me in that.

This is the link : https://www.myshopingkart.com/clothing/men/haute-denim-navy-blue-main.html

### [image: Configurable Swatches]

### This the error when I click on the swathces..

[image: Configurable Swatches-error]

Comment: check if your select is inside of <form>

Comment: I didn't alter any code. So its definately inside the form. Disabling Magento's Native Configurable Swatch is making it work, but I want Config swatches to be worked. There must be a solution. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You have problems with Javascript:

```
$('.btn-cart-single').bind("click",function(){  
        re = 1;
        proId = $("#proId").val();
        curQty = $('#qty').val();
        minQty = $('#min_qty_stock').val();
        maxQty = $('#max_qty_stock').val();
        qtyStock = $('#qty_stock').val();
        qtyStock_1 = $('#qty_stock').val();
        if ( manage_stock == 0 ){
            qtyStock = maxQty + 1;
        }
        if( minQty==''&&maxQty==''&&qtyStock=='' ){
            alert('Please, select item');
            return false;
        }....
```

When you try to test in console ()

```
        minQty = jQuery('#min_qty_stock').val();
        maxQty = jQuery('#max_qty_stock').val();
        qtyStock = jQuery('#qty_stock').val();
```

The 3 vars show empty ""
Try to check when the elements #min_qty_stock, #max_qty_stock, #qty_stock is filled

```
<span class="quantity-box">

                    <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="1" title="Qty" class="quantity-input qty">                     
                    <input type="hidden" id="min_qty_stock" name="min_qty_stock" value="">                      
                    <input type="hidden" id="max_qty_stock" name="max_qty_stock" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" id="qty_stock" name="qty_stock" value="">
                    <input type="button" class="quantity-controls quantity-plus" onclick="$('qty').value=Number($('qty').value)+1" value="">    
                    <input type="button" class="quantity-controls quantity-minus" onclick="if(Number($('qty').value)>1){$('qty').value=Number($('qty').value)-1;}" value="">                    
                </span>
```

Comment: But when I disable the Configurable Swatch, its working. And the script remains same as you have stated above. Then What changes should I make to get the Configurable Swatches working?

Comment: Can you disable? I will check it

Comment: Sure. Wait a minute. Are u on Gtalk or Skype? Mine westzonesolution1@gmail.com / Skype: amitretail2008

Comment: The Config Swatch is disabled.

Comment: Now when I make in console : minQty = jQuery('#min_qty_stock').val();
   maxQty = jQuery('#max_qty_stock').val();
   qtyStock = jQuery('#qty_stock').val(); it show me qty's. Check please my answer. "Try to check when the elements #min_qty_stock, #max_qty_stock, #qty_stock are filled"

Comment: Please dont mind if I am bothering you. I am new to Firebug and really appoligise that not understand consol very well. So as an Expert if you help me out to chage the code then I will be very much oblized.

Comment: >>> minQty = jQuery('#min_qty_stock').val(1); maxQty = jQuery('#max_qty_stock').val(); qtyStock = jQuery('#qty_stock').val();
"20"
>>> minQty = jQuery('#min_qty_stock').val(1); maxQty = jQuery('#max_qty_stock').val(1000); qtyStock = jQuery('#qty_stock').val();
"20"

Comment: Check the difference in the div.quantity-box when you disable the color swatches and when you enable

Comment: Check the above console when I make this >>> minQty = jQuery('#min_qty_stock').val(1); maxQty = jQuery('#max_qty_stock').val(1000); qtyStock = jQuery('#qty_stock').val(); "20" then its working. So where is the script resides? Is that correct procedure?

Comment: The problem is... These element not has value when you enable color swatch. When you click to addcart... The javascript check these params, these params are empty (when you enable swatch). Please check the phtml in div.quantity-box and these 3 elements (max_qty_stock, min_qty_stock, etc) and fix the problem.

Comment: I understood now. But how do I fix them if I am not getting the script? I am searching everywhere but couldn't find the script. Where do I get the the script file. The script & (div.quantity-box and these 3 elements (max_qty_stock, min_qty_stock, etc)) not in the view.phtml. Your help is very much appriciated man.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the javascript error from firebug ,if there isn't any javascript bug or you are unable to debug it. Simply what you can do is disable your current configurable swatches and Try this swatches extension - https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher

Comment: I want to use Magento's own Configurable Swatches. So what error is there in my script.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved by adding the following javascript code (just before the comment **// validated configurable**):

```
// validate configurable swatches
$('.swatch-link').bind("click",function(){
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id.replace("swatch","");
    value = $('#minQty_'+id).val();
    $('#min_qty_stock').val(value);
    value = $('#maxQty_'+id).val();
    $('#max_qty_stock').val(value);
    value = $('#qty_stock_'+id).val();
    $('#qty_stock').val(value);
    manage_stock = $('#manage_stock_'+id).val();
});
```

in the following file:

**app/design/frontend/[YOUR_THEME]/default/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml**